# Confused in selecting ancestor name

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to print ancestor node name using XSLT.

Below is my XSLT.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="(//title)[1]"/>

<xsl:template match="title">
<xsl:value-of select="name(ancestor::node())"/>
</xsl:template>
```

And my XML is as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
    <!--ancestor-->
    <cd>
        <!--parent-->
        <title name="titleName" property="propertyName">Empire Burlesque</title>
        <!--self-->
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <!--following-sibling-->
        <country>USA</country>
        <!--following-sibling-->
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <!--following-sibling-->
        <price>10.90</price>
        <!--following-sibling-->
        <year>1985</year>
        <!--following-sibling-->
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

Here when I use the below statement.

```
<xsl:value-of select="name(../..)"/>
```

else when I use

```
<xsl:value-of select="name(ancestor::node())"/>
```

or

```
<xsl:value-of select="name(ancestor::*)"/>
```

it is giving me the below Exception

```
XSLT 2.0 Debugging Error: Error: file:///C:/Users/u0138039/Desktop/Training%20Docs/XSLT%20Training/Sample.xsl:209: Wrong occurrence to match required sequence type -   Details: -     XPTY0004: The parameter value ('3' item(s)) at position '1' of the 'name' function has the wrong occurrence to match the sequence type node() ('zero or one')
```

but to get the parent name, when I use

```
<xsl:value-of select="name(parent::*)"/>
```

please let me know why this working for `parent` but not for `ancestor`.

This is very confusing. How can I get the `ancestor` name using something like `<xsl:value-of select="name(ancestor::node())"`.

Thanks

Comment: The name of which ancestor? If you use `ancestor::node()` in the context of the `title` element then you select the `cd` element and the `catalog` element and the document node, as they are all ancestor nodes. `<xsl:value-of select="name(../..)"/>` should work to output the name of the grandparent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ancestor` axis contains **all** ancestors of the context node: its parent, its grandparent, its great-grandparent, etc. all the way up to the root node.

When you ask for a name of an ancestor, you must select **one** of the nodes on the `ancestor` axis. For example:

```
<xsl:value-of select="name(ancestor::*[last()])"/>
```

will return `"catalog"` in your example (note that ancestor is a reverse axis).

OTOH, this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ancestor::*/name()"/>
```

will (in XSLT 2.0) return `"catalog cd"` - i.e. a space-separated list of all the node's ancestor names.